# I type php artisan package:discover and get error

Tags: php, laravel

`php artisan package:discover`

> error:"There are no commands defined in the package namespace"

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: Does `php artisan` return anything? Is `package:discover` in there?

Comment: Please add more info about your project

Comment: It looks like you found the solution ... any chance you can share it with the rest of us? I've run into the same thing. And I'm sure I'll figure it out before you get a chance to reply, it definitely would have saved some time.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run `composer self-update` as I believe the package discovery process requires a more recent version of the composer.

Comment: thanks for your response.Although i have found a solution to that issues.thanks

Comment: Great, let us know the solution and if this helps you up the answer.